# Get weights after training from Sagemaker Estimator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Tensorflow's Estimator provides a method to get desired variable values after training/testing using [get_variable_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value).
Does there exist similar functionality in Sagemaker's Estimator, so that I am able to obtain weights after my model is trained.

Answer (score 1):

For the `Estimator` object in the SageMaker Python SDK, after you call `fit()` you can call get the S3 URL of your model artifacts with

```
model_artifacts_url = estimator.create_model().model_data
```

The model itself is saved into your S3 bucket as a tarball at this location.  So from here you can get the model parameters out of S3.

Comment: I did try using the `get_variable_value` method to get weights from the Estimator. While it works for a [tensorflow estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) locally, [Sagemaker's Tensorflow Estimator](http://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker.tensorflow.html#tensorflow-estimator) does not seem to have the `get_variable_value` or the 
`get_variable_names` method.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand what you mean.  I'll update my answer.